# ¿Por qué no puedo ejecutar esta aritmética básica?

Tags: haskell

Estoy empezando a aprender Haskell con el libro [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), vengo de usar Python que es un lenguaje imperativo. Estoy usando el intérprete `ghci` y me topé con lo siguiente:

```
Prelude> 5 * -3

<interactive>:2:1:    
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix `*' [infixl 7] and prefix `-' [infixl 6] in the same infix expression
```

Por el error entiendo que no puedo mezclar `*` con `-` en la expresión, en el libro no explican la razón por la que no funciona, solo recomiendan usar paréntesis:

```
Prelude> 5 * (-3)
-15
```

Se me ocurre que `-` es tratada como una función y es por eso que al encerrarla entra paréntesis es evaluada primero antes de multiplicar. Entonces intenté lo siguiente:

```
Prelude> -(5)
-5
Prelude> +(5)

<interactive>:9:1: parse error on input `+'
```

Pues ahora si que estoy confundido. ¿por qué no es posible multiplicar un número negativo sin la necesidad de usar paréntesis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La razón es: **porque la gramática no lo permite**. Déjame entrar un poco en detalle acerca de esto.

> Nota: Como sabrás, en haskell los operadores son funciones en notación
>   [infijo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation).

Ahora veamos el error, dice:

```
Precedence parsing error
    cannot mix `*' [infixl 7] and prefix `-' [infixl 6] in the same infix expression
```

¿Qué significa esto? Bueno, para empezar definamos qué quieren decir con `infixl 7` e `infixl 6`, en su gramática hay algo así:

```
infixr 9 .
infixr 8 ^, ^^, **
infixl 7 *, /, `quot`, `rem`, `div`, `mod`
infixl 6 +, -
infixr 5 :
infix 4 ==, /=, <, <=, >=, >
infixr 3 &&
infixr 2 ||
infixl 1 >>, >>=
infixr 1 =<<
infixr 0 $, $!, `seq`
```

> Nota: Esto lo puedes [ver acá, en el estándar prelude](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html).

Lo que te quieren decir el error es que no puedes mezclar elementos `infixl 7` con `infixl 6`, esa es la misma razón por la que no puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
Prelude> 5 * +3
```

Dado que salta el error de sintaxis ([lo puedes probar acá](https://tryhaskell.org/)):

```
parse error on input `+'
```

Espera, si es un error de sintaxis, ¿por qué el error anterior es diferente?

Resulta que el `operador unario "-"` es muy especial y es usado por otras partes de la gramática, así que en teoría esto se va por una rama diferente del árbol de sintaxis y da error en otro lado.

Si quieres leer más sobre esto último puedes [ver acá (en inglés)](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/NegativeSyntax).

Comment: Ajá, entiendo. Interesante lo de los `infixl` e `infixr`, ¿cómo hago para verlos desde el intéprete?

Comment: Buena pregunta, no sé cómo verlo desde el intérprete. Lo puedes ver desde el famoso `standard prelude` (agregado a la respuesta).